# how to add formcontrol name based on user input

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

My intent is to create a JSON object like as shown in the image with angular 8 forms[image]

issue is the control name is defined by user with a `text input` (retail, wholesale, wholesale_2 etc..), this in turn will contain formArrays of unit and price, user will be free to add as many unit-price elements.

So far I am able to achieve adding the unit-price grouping with button click [+] in image but a single orange block. how to make it dynamic

```
  prodid = null;
  prodgroup: FormGroup;
  unitprices: FormArray;
  pgcontainers =[];
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.prodgroup = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]),
      image: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      pgroup: this.fb.array([this.pricegroup()]),
      unitprices:  this.fb.array([this.unitprice()])
    })
  }


  addunitpriceClick(): void{
    this.unitprices = this.prodgroup.get('unitprices') as FormArray;
    this.unitprices.push(this.unitprice());
  }
  unitprice(): FormGroup{
    return this.fb.group({
      unit:['',[Validators.required] ],
      price:['',[Validators.required] ]
    })
  }
```

Comment: What I understand you need json keys defined by input? Like user will add Key (formControlName) and value by himself?

Comment: Or I think the issue is if you click the + button. All the orange boxes will have unit and price?

Comment: Yes, users will define key with text input and and values which is an array of JSON objects(orange box content). Once I type in key then push [add] it should add another orange block with only [+] button and two text field one for unit and one for price.

Comment: I will create a stackBlitz Demo for you for a better understanding of your program.

Comment: Will be helpful, just want user defined input as keys for formgroup

Answer (score 0):

Use addControl to dynamically add formcontrol to the reactive form.

Define the text input in your component and use ngModel

In Component.ts

```
textInput: string;

addFormControl() {
    this.prodgroup.addControl(textInput, this.fb.array([this.unitprice()]));
}
```

Comment: As far as I know we can not combine ```ngModel``` and ```ReactiveForms```

Answer (score 0):

Disclamer: It's not an answer just a suggest

You has not a valid JSON, I suggest you a json like

```
{
  name:...
  imagen:...
  detail:[
     name:...
     prices:[
        {
         unit:...,
         price:...
        }
     ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Actually your JSON format is structured one which has fixed keys (schema) mine is semi-structured. Both are valid JSON format. I prefer storing it in this way because of storage efficiency